# MongoDB Java Query: Pattern.compile(text) ( SQL like '%' ) results

Tags: java, json, mongodb, rest

I'm using Restfull webservice to connect to MongoDB server and to return JSON. 
While I'm searching for a specific phrase I get in return the entire JSON whereas I only need to get a certain part of that JSON, i.e. object in that JSON that includes searched phrase. 
I'm using:

`Pattern.compile("first")`  `( SQL equivalent like '%' )` for it. but it returns entire JSON. How can I fix it?

Here's my JSON:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("553743843bf93901552383d8"),
    "name" : "Example Data", 
    "Example Array" : [ 
         {
            "_id" : ObjectId("553743843bf93901552383d9"),
            "name" : "Example Name!",
            "html" : "<div class='container'>This is first html</div>
         }, 
         {
            "_id" : ObjectId("553743843bf93901552383d9"),
            "name" : "Example Name2",
            "html" : "<div class='container'>This is second html</div>
         }
                     ]
}
```

and the webservice:

```
@GET
@Path("example/{text}/")
@Produces("application/json;charset=utf-8")
public String getText(@PathParam("text") String text){

DB db = getConnection().getDB(content);
DBCollection collection = db.getCollection(examples);

BasicDBObject matchTextSearch = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("html", Pattern.compile(text)));

AggregationOutput output = collection.aggregate(matchTextSearch);
BasicDBList parts = new BasicDBList();
    for (DBObject result : output.results()) {
        parts = result;
    }

    return JSON.serialize(parts);
}
```

Comment: Can you add an example of the output are are getting and the output you would like?

Comment: Im getting the entire array, but I would like get only searched word which in

Answer (score 0):

After looking your documents and your code I think you missed to unwind `Example Array` and then used match as

```
@GET
@Path("example/{text}/")
@Produces("application/json;charset=utf-8")
public String getText(@PathParam("text") String text){

DB db = getConnection().getDB(content);
DBCollection collection = db.getCollection(examples);

DBObject unwind = new BasicDBObject("$unwind", "$Example Array");

BasicDBObject matchTextSearch = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("Example Array.html", Pattern.compile(text)));

AggregationOutput output = collection.aggregate(unwind,matchTextSearch);
BasicDBList parts = new BasicDBList();
    for (DBObject result : output.results()) {
        parts = result;
    }

    return JSON.serialize(parts);
}
```

Comment: Error: `javax.servlet.ServletException: com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "172.xx.xx.xxx:27017" , "errmsg" : "exception: bad query: BadValue unknown top level operator: $Example Array.html" , "code" : 16810 , "ok" : 0.0}`

Comment: I was do it with `$group` but can't get whict i want result

Comment: Problem with unwinding,  is your array name `Example Array` ?

Comment: No it's not but I changed its name to correspond to my original project.

Comment: @FaridValiyev I removed in match `$Example Array.html` to `Example Array.html` think it work

Comment: I think problem with `Pattern.compile(text)`  check this `text` fields what contains and pattern.compile like regular expression so any of `text` data match with `html` then it prints all data if you want to exact match then use this `new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("Example Array.html",text));`